# Word - Auto Create UserForm Textboxes

Tags: vba, ms-word, automation, userform

I have a Userform where it auto creates labels and text boxes. The problem is after created I don't know the name of text box 1. I was thinking it would be TextBox1 but it isn't. How would I go about naming them TextBox1 then TextBox2 and so on? Code in question is under "AddLine".

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim TBs(9) As Object
Set TBs(0) = TextBox1: Set TBs(1) = TextBox2: Set TBs(2) = TextBox3
Set TBs(3) = TextBox4: Set TBs(4) = TextBox5: Set TBs(5) = TextBox6
Set TBs(6) = TextBox7: Set TBs(7) = TextBox8: Set TBs(8) = TextBox9
Set TBs(9) = TextBox10:

For i = 0 To Amount
    With ActiveDocument
        If .Bookmarks("href" & i + 1).Range = ".jpg" Then
            .Bookmarks("href" & i + 1).Range _
            .InsertBefore TBs(i)
            .Bookmarks("src" & i + 1).Range _
            .InsertBefore TBs(i)
            .Bookmarks("alt" & i + 1).Range _
            .InsertBefore TBs(i)
        End If
    End With
Next



UserForm1.Hide

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ".jpg "
        .Replacement.Text = ".jpg"

        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "/ "
        .Replacement.Text = "/"

        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll



    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ".jpg.jpg"
        .Replacement.Text = ".jpg"

        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub


Private Sub AddLine_Click()


Dim theTextbox As Object
Dim textboxCounter As Long

For textboxCounter = 1 To Amount
    Set theTextbox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "test" & textboxCounter, True)
    With theTextbox

        .Width = 200
        .Left = 70
        .Top = 30 * textboxCounter
    End With

Next

Dim theLabel As Object
Dim labelCounter As Long

For labelCounter = 1 To Amount
    Set theLabel = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test" & labelCounter, True)
    With theLabel
        .Caption = "Image" & labelCounter
        .Left = 20
        .Width = 50
        .Top = 30 * labelCounter
    End With

    With UserForm1
        .Height = Amount * 30 + 100
    End With

    With CommandButton1
        .Top = Amount * 30 + 40
    End With

    With CommandButton2
        .Top = Amount * 30 + 40
    End With


Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is already giving it names like `test1`, `test2`, etc., that is the second parameter in the `.Add` method:

```
Set theTextbox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "test" & textboxCounter, True)
```

Intellisense shows this pretty clearly:

[image]

If you don't like that, I think you can always change it from the `.Name` property:

Simply assign it a name while it's being added.

```
For textboxCounter = 1 To Amount
    Set theTextbox = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "test" & textboxCounter, True)
    With theTextbox
        .Name = "TextBox_" & i
        .Width = 200
        .Left = 70
        .Top = 30 * textboxCounter
    End With

Next
```

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

So you have this assignment here:

```
Set TBs(0) = TextBox1: Set TBs(1) = TextBox2: Set TBs(2) = TextBox3
Set TBs(3) = TextBox4: Set TBs(4) = TextBox5: Set TBs(5) = TextBox6
Set TBs(6) = TextBox7: Set TBs(7) = TextBox8: Set TBs(8) = TextBox9
Set TBs(9) = TextBox10:
```

Use of `Option Explicit` at the top of your module would have warned you about these.  When you run this, **if you would have taken normal steps to debug, you should see that `TBs(0)`, etc., are all assigned `Nothing`.** (And then you could have asked a better question: "Why are my variables all `Nothing`?", etc...  I mention these things not to lambaste you but to show you how to solve your own issues (or at least get the pertinent information so you may ask better questions in the future!

**Why?**

Because there is no such object in scope as `TextBox1`, etc.

**Why not?**

Because you do not create the textboxes until later in your code, so at the time of assignment, that array is holding all `Nothing`.

**how to fix it?**

I do not think you can refer to controls created at run-time in this way, because the code generally will not compile (again, `Option Explicit` would've alerted you to this; you should **ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS** use this at the top of each module).

You should be able to assign like:

`Set TBs(0) = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox_1")`, etc.  Make sure that you use the correct name as assigned in the `.Add` method (or as specified in the `.Name` property when you add the Textboxes to the form.

**NOTE** You *must* make this assignment *after* the TextBox(es) have been added to the UserForm, otherwise an error will occur.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried changing the first "test" to TextBox1 before but it still wouldn't work with the code up top. I will try it again.

Comment: Yeah tried it again. I tried changing it too TextBox1 and TextBox but the code up top still isn't recognizing the name. I will keep trying some different things as well.

Comment: OK well that was not your question at first... you should explain better next time please. I will revise my answer to address this problem.

Comment: Hi JohnB, revision above should explain why your code is not working (there are two reasons at least). I think I address them both. Let me know how that works for you!

Comment: Everything you said makes a lot of sense. I've been coding in VB for about 2 weeks. I appreciate your suggestions. I am out of time tonight but I will look into it further later in the week.

Comment: David, I followed your suggestions the best I could and got it working somewhat. I put the resulting code at [New Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846550/word-vb-error-5941-and-for-loop). I am getting an error now but the code works.